# UINavigationBar doesn't appear in UITableViewController XCode 7, Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, xcode7

I embedded in the Navigation Controller.

The Navigation Controller is shown in the Storyboard and connected with the `UITableViewController`. The `UINavigationBar` is also shown in the `UITableViewController` in the Storyboard file and I also set a title, which is also shown in the Storyboard file!

When I am running my app and I am presenting the `UITableViewController` everything is shown of it EXCEPT the `UINavigationBar`.

Comment: could you show some code ?

Answer (score 0):

Default behavior in `UINavigationController` is to show the `UINavigationBar`.

So if it is not there, it means you either hid it in code, or in `Interface Builder`